Understanding Feynman: why gravity is not a spin-0 theory?
I'm struggling to understand a certain paragraph in Feynman's "lectures on gravitation". It's lecture 3, why gravity cannot be a spin-0 theory. Here's the text:

The rejection of spin-zero theories of gravitation is made on the basis of the gravitational behavior of the binding energies. We ask the question, what is the attraction between moving objects? [...] We may for example calculate the mutual attraction of the two masses of gas; the experimental evidence on gravity suggests that the force is greater if the gases are hotter. 
We know what happens in electrodynamics. The electric forces are unchanged by random motions of the particles. Now the interaction energy is proportional to the expectation value of the operator $\gamma_{t}$, which is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$ Since the potential resulting from this operator is not velocity dependent the proportionality factor must go as $\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$. This means that the interaction energy resulting from the operator 1, corresponding to the spin-0 field, would be proportional to $\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$. In other words, the spin-zero theory would predict that the attraction between masses of hot gas would be smaller than for cool gas (which is wrong).

What I don't understand is:

Where does it come from that the interaction energy is proportional to the expectation value of the operator $\gamma_t$? I know that $\gamma$ is the Lorentzian factor, coming from special relativity and increasing mass (or energy) due to (relativistic) velocity. However, what I don't understand is why the interaction energy is calculated here and why it's equal to $\gamma$.
Why is the "potential resulting from this operator not velocity dependent"? Is it because the  potential  $ U = G \frac{m_1 }{r}$ simply has no velocity in its equation? However, if there is more then one mass summing up to the central mass, and moving relative to each other, then the kinetic energy of all those particles adds to the total mass (therefore energy, therefore potential), for example inside protons and neutrons, the kinetic energy of gluons and quarks adds to the total mass. Therefore, the potential should be velocity dependent?
What is "operator 1"?
I find the sentence "This means that the interaction energy resulting from the operator 1, corresponding to the spin-0 field, would be proportional to $\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$." especially confusing, as two sentences above he said that the interaction energy is $1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ - but now, it's the opposite. Why??

The question is: I'm supposedly missing some background information to understand Feynman's reasoning here. What is it?

(Leaving as a comment since it is not directly answering the question the OP asked) Regardless of Feynman's argument from the 60's, today we have much more direct lines of evidence that gravity is spin-2, for example using gravitational waves detected from GW170817, one can show using Bayesian model selection that the data are much better described by a pure spin-2 field over a pure spin-0 field https://link.aps.org/accepted/10.1103/PhysRevLett.123.011102

Thank you, Andrew (interesting link!)! However, the point of my question really is that I want to understand the reasoning of Feynman here, the single steps of his inferences... As I really don't get the reasoning behind it, maybe I'm missing some background information.

Does "operator 1" just mean multiplying by 1?

You’re supposed to ask one question per post.

@my2cts yes... The question is: How can I understand this reasoning? I assume there some background information I'm missing and that's presumably related to all four points.

I re-arranged the question to better make clear that it's one question
